# Multi line text box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, multiline

I have a multi line text box like :

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="txtform" ID="txtWhom" runat="server" Height="78px" 
     Rows="10" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

say I write the following text in that text box :

> Dear Sir,
>   General Manager,
>   HSBC.

when I take that text in a variable in the vb.net code behind... and send it to a crystal report to show ... only ... the first line is shown... in that case only "Dear Sir," is shown ... but I want all the text ....
What Can I do ?

Comment: in the vb code I took the text value of the text box by "txtWhom.Text"

Comment: Have you checked that what txtWhom.Text contains. If it have whole text that you have written then modify your crystal report to show multiline text..

Comment: Check the value by attaching a debugger it seems you have not set text to multiline in crystal report

Comment: On textfield in crystal report, right click for "Format". You'll see the checkbox "Can grow". Select the checkbox.
ref [this](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/60817.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use "Can Grow" option for that text object in Crystal report.
```

`=>Right Click -> Text Object

=>Select Format Object
=>Use Can grow option in the dialog box.`

It enables for variable length fields to grow vertically in the report and word wrap automatically. A maximum number of lines can be set with this option to control rogue or large data elements.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if your entered string includes carriage return & line feed chars that Crystal is not dealing with properly. You may need to strip those out or replace them with correct characters that Crystal expects.